# SQL Sum in Multiple join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling for the setup for this. This is the setup of the first table. The first query needs to only apply to items past a certain date, say 2012-06-01.

```
|                  Table: TIMELOG                  |
| INQUIRY_ID | … |      LOGMINS    | … |  OPERID   | … |    EDATE    |
|     2      |   |       45        |   |  bob      |   | 2012-05-01  |
|     5      |   |       3         |   |  richard  |   | 2012-06-02  |
|     5      |   |       12        |   |  bob      |   | 2012-07-01  |
|     5      |   |       15        |   |  paul     |   | 2012-07-01  |
|     6      |   |       10        |   |  paul     |   | 2012-07-01  |
```

The query then needs to go into a different table using INQUIRY_ID and get some additional fields (there is only one entry per INQUIRY_ID in this next table:

```
|                  Table: INQUIRY                  |
| INQUIRY_ID | … |  CATEGORY_ID    | … |  PROD_ID  |
|     2      |   |       45        |   |  6        |
|     3      |   |       3         |   |  50       |
|     4      |   |       12        |   |  3        |
|     5      |   |       15        |   |  67       |
|     6      |   |       10        |   |  2        |
```

Once we have the CATEGORY_ID and PROD_ID the "friendly names" for those are in their own seperate tables

```
|            Table: CATEGORY            |
| CATEGORY_ID | … |      CATNAME        |
|     45      |   |       Server        |
|     3       |   |       Workstation   |
|     12      |   |       Phones        |
|     15      |   |       Backup        |  
|     10      |   |       Network       |

|            Table: PROD                |
| PROD_ID     | … |      PRODDESC       |
|     6       |   |       SBS 2003      |
|     50      |   |       Windows 7     |
|     3       |   |       iPhone        |
|     67      |   |       Buexec        |  
|     2       |   |       SwitchF       |
```

I'd then like to total the LOGMINS field, bearing in mind sometimes it will have multiple LOGMINS per INQUIRY_ID To finish up as

```
| INQUIRY_ID | … |      TOTAL      | … |  CATNAME         | … |   PRODDESC    |
|     2      |   |       45        |   |     Server       |   |   SBS 2003    |
|     5      |   |       30        |   |     Workstation  |   |   Windows 7   |
|     6      |   |       10        |   |     Phones       |   |   iPhone      |
```

I'm sorry for the extraordinary amount of detail, the queries I have tried just bomb out, my skill in SQL blows up when I get into nested queries and multiple joins. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Query I am running now:

```
 select 
 timelog.INQUIRY_ID,
 SUM (logmins) AS Total,
 catname,
 proddesc,
 EDATE
from
 timelog
inner join inquiry on timelog.inquiry_id=inquiry.inquiry_id
inner join category on inquiry.category_id = category.category_id
inner join prod on inquiry.prod_id = prod.prod_id
where EDATE > '2013-07-01'
group by
timelog.INQUIRY_ID,
catname,
proddesc,
edate
order by timelog.INQUIRY_ID desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables your data is in together, then `group` on the data that you are keeping constant, and `sum` the fields you want to add

```
select 
  inquiry.inquiry_id,
  SUM(logmins),
  catname,
  proddesc
from
   timelog
    inner join inquiry on timelog.inquiry_id=inquiry.inquiry_id
    inner join category on inquiry.category_id = category.category_id
    inner join prod on inquiry.prod_id = prod.prod_id
group by
  inquiry.inquiry_id,
  catname,
  proddesc
```

Comment: That works but it is pulling back multiple INQUIRY_ID in the results that are the same, what I need to end up with is it totalling all the rows that have the SAME inquiry_ID and just adding them in as one total per inquiry_ID. Is this possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Trinitrotoluene Have you added some other fields, or are there other differences between the rows?

Comment: Hi, sorry this is my fault I should have been more specific. Some of the tables I outlined before have a good deal more columns with more data in that I don't need, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @Trinitrotoluene The query as detailed above should return a single row for each combination of enquiry/catname/proddesc.  Can you give an example of where that isn't the case?

Comment: I've updated original question with the query I am running, this returns for example:

     45558 26 Backup Configuration 2013-08-02 13:41:06.000

     45558 3 Backup Configuration 2013-08-02 13:41:17.000 those being two rows as an example, sorry for formatting

Comment: @Trinitrotoluene Yes, you'll get a different row for each value of EDate. Which Date do you want to show? The first one : Add `MIN(EDATE)` and remove Edate from the group by